# Uncaught Error: Failed to load routed module (viewmodels/home/index). Details: The 'resourceName' parameter must be a 'string'

Tags: javascript, breeze, durandal

When adding a new page or a lookup using Durandal/Breeze/Knockout I would keep getting the following error after doing the multitude of steps to get all the data loaded and the pages created.

Uncaught Error: Failed to load routed module (viewmodels/home/index). Details: The 'resourceName' parameter  must be a 'string'

Answer (score 3):

I found that ususally this error would occur because I incorrectly entered in a repository in the unitofwork.js script:

```
this.unitConditions = repository.create(provider, "UnitCondition", routeconfig.unitConditionsUrl, breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache);
```

the issue usually was pluralization.  I would forget an 's' and then I would get that error.  It took me a while to figure this all out so I thought I would post the error and my solution for anyone else with that issue.